# How can I know if a connected port is a usb

Tags: python, usb, deviceid

I'm using this code :

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):

    print usb.DeviceID
```

how can I know if the DeviceID given is an ID of USB

Comment: Someone will probably have a better answer than this, but I think you could use the winreg library and cross reference the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? There might be a better way to go about this.

Comment: Actually this is irrelevant already but am trying to find a way to find a usb path using its ID